# Excel Macro or Function: Populate a cell range (Column A) with a looped values (from another sheet) if cell is not blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need help for someone trying to learn macro coding.

Sheet 1 has two Columns A & B. Sheet 2, Col A has a range of value. 
I wanted to fill Sheet 1 Column B with a value on Sheet 2 Column A if Sheet 1 Column A cell is not empty.

Illustration below.

```
Sheet2 Col A
Brian, 
David,
Nicole,
Aspen,

Col A                  
Apple         
Banana        
Orange        
Lemon         
Mango         
Strawberry    
Grape
```

Col B should get filled by looping with the names, Brian for Apple and then David for Banana, and so on and then go back to David and so on until Grape for Nicole..

Please help provide with a function or macro vba code to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A" & MOD(ROW()+3,4)+1)
```

This assumes the names are in `A1:A4`

Edit: and I just thought of a way to use `INDEX` instead:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A$1:A$4,MOD(ROW()+3,4)+1)
```

`MOD` will return the remainder of the row number divided by `n` (in this case, `4`). This will result in a number between `0` and `3` (`n-1`), inclusively. the sequence for rows `1-6` is `1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2`.

By adding `3` (`n-1`) to the row number, I can get the sequence for rows `1-6` to become `0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1`

Then adding `1` to the mod makes the sequence: `1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2`, which I can then use as the index for the table of names

For 12 names you will want to use:

```
=INDEX(F$1:F$12,MOD(ROW()+11,12)+1)
```

Comment: Hi!

Can you please explain this part of the expression, MOD(ROW()+3,4)+1)? If for example I have 12 names and 200 fruits. :)

I tried the INDEX option and it loops for 5 names instead of 12.

Comment: Very nice @cybernetic.nomad ++

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems to work for my case. :) One little thing, The sheet has a header and the function starts with the second item on the list. How to adjust to have it start on the first item on the list?

Comment: Sorry, after checking further, I forgot that it should stop assigning names if there are no more fruits on Column A. :)

Comment: That can be fixed with `IF(A1<>"",formula,"")`